# How is narrowing typescript type by casting, wrong?

Tags: typescript

I am running a javascript application written in typescript.
Somewhere in the code I have something like this

```
{
  title: props.value?.name as string
}
```

A friend told me that this is not a good way to type cast because we pretend like undefined is not there.
I do not understand this because this works and I do not see it ever breaking.

Could you explain to me how is narrowing a typescript type by type-casting it, not good and should never be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to use optional chaining, then you do not know if the property *actually* exists:

```
const props = {
    value: Math.random() < 0.5 ? undefined : { name: 'foo' }
};
const someObj = {
    title: props.value?.name as string
}
```

If the `value` turns out to be `undefined`, then the `someObj` will be:

```
{
    title: undefined
}
```

but the `title` property will still be typed as a *string*, which means that you'd be permitted to do

```
someObj.title.startsWith('bar')
```

which will throw a runtime error, ultimately caused by the incorrect type assertion.

Since you don't know whether the `value` object exists, you should type the `title` as `string | undefined` instead in case the optional chaining fails - that way, references to `someObj.title` will have to narrow it to a string before using string methods on it:

```
const props = {
    value: Math.random() < 0.5 ? undefined : { name: 'foo' }
};
const someObj = {
    title: props.value?.name as (string | undefined)
    // above type assertion not necessary if TS can already recognize
    // that it's a string or undefined
    // like in this example
};
if (someObj.title) {
    console.log(someObj.title.startsWith('bar'));
} else {
    console.log('it is undefined');
}
```

If you *do* know for certain that the `value` object exists, and that its `name` property is a string, then remove the optional chaining:

```
const someObj = {
    title: props.value.name as string
};
```